# postman how to set an environment url variable after importing a large amount of endpoints

Tags: postman

I've just imported around 1000+ endpoints into a new collection from a swagger endpoint (awesome feature btw).

What i would like to do now is for this collection add an env variable into the url as its the same collection from Dev to Stage to Prod. 
A simple regex or string match substitution would be great but I cant find anyway to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the exported collection JSON we can see objects of the following form:

```
        "url": {
            "raw": "https://example.com/user",
            "host": [
                "https://example.com"
            ],
            "path": [
                "user"
            ]
        }
```

The goal is to convert them to:

```
        "url": {
            "raw": "{{someUrl}}/user",
            "host": [
                "{{someUrl}}"
            ],
            "path": [
                "user"
            ]
        }
```

Using `sed` we can achive this as follows:

1. Export collection to `postman_collection.json`
2. Use `sed` to [replace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112024) `https://example.com` with `{{someUrl}}`:

   ```
   sed -i -- 's/https:\/\/example.com/{{someUrl}}/g' postman_collection.json
   ```
3. Re-import the collection
4. Create [Postman environment variable](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_environments) `someUrl` in Dev, Stage, and Prod environments.